# Updating time series with another time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

Suppose I have two time series

```
(x <- xts(c(5,4:10), Sys.Date()+3:10))
(y <- xts(1:6, Sys.Date()+1:6))

merge(x,y)

            x  y
2018-04-20 NA  1
2018-04-21 NA  2
2018-04-22  5  3
2018-04-23  4  4
2018-04-24  5  5
2018-04-25  6  6
2018-04-26  7 NA
2018-04-27  8 NA
2018-04-28  9 NA
2018-04-29 10 NA
```

How do I get a time series that takes the value of `y` if it is present, but falls back to `x` only if `y` does not have a value at a particular date? For example, I want the values in `z` as below:

```
            x  y z
2018-04-20 NA  1 1
2018-04-21 NA  2 2 
2018-04-22  5  3 3 
2018-04-23  4  4 4 
2018-04-24  5  5 5
2018-04-25  6  6 6
2018-04-26  7 NA 7 
2018-04-27  8 NA 8 
2018-04-28  9 NA 9
2018-04-29 10 NA 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution, and it does not use `ifelse()`.

```
# Merge the two objects first
z <- merge(x,y)

# Create a new column from a copy of 'y'
z$z <- z$y

# Missing values in column 'z'
zNA <- is.na(z$z)

# Fill all missing values in column 'z' with values from column 'x'
z[zNA, "z"] <- z[zNA, "x"]
```

I personally avoid `ifelse()` because the object it returns is not always intuitively predictable.

Comment: It is true that using `ifelse()` requires a bit of testing and I've had a few surprises using it too confidently in the past. But the fact that the output has the same shape as the test makes it a powerful vectorised function. I agree that the class of the output might be unexpected sometimes. 
Anyway, great answer as always

Answer (score 2):

Would that solve your problem ?

```
z <- rbind(x,y)
z <- z[!duplicated(z)]
```

**Edit**:

Note that `rbind()` binds `xts` objects by row in order of priority, i.e. the   rows of `y` will be before rows of `x` because `y` was put before `x` in the    function call

```
> rbind(y, x) 
           [,1] 
2018-04-21    1 
2018-04-22    2 
2018-04-23    3 
2018-04-23    5 
2018-04-24    4 
2018-04-24    4 
2018-04-25    5 
2018-04-25    5 
2018-04-26    6 
2018-04-26    6 
2018-04-27    7 
2018-04-28    8 
2018-04-29    9 
2018-04-30   10
```

Then I noticed that `z[!duplicated(z)]` is not correct actually. The duplicates you want to take out are duplicates in index so try that out.

```
z <- rbind(y, x) 
z <- z[!duplicated(index(z))]
```

I am a fervent user of `xts` and I always try to use its functions because they usually do all the work for you in a very readable and natural fashion. But     when I can't find my way out of it I often use the powerful `ifelse()`, prince  of efficiency and destroyer of ambiguity.

```
z <- merge(x, y) 
zz <- ifelse(is.na(z[, 2]), z[, 1], z[, 2])
```

Now `zz` is not an `xts` object anymore so have to do

```
zz <- xts(zz, index(z))
```

But you will be left with duplicates. Since I don't know from your answer if    you actually want to keep them, I'll leave you the choice.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Close, not clear from my example above but in instances where x and y have values on the same date, I only want y's values.

Comment: Then you can always get yourself where you want with the `ifelse` but it might become a bit less readable.. I'll edit my answer